# Getting [TypeError: no access] in WebStorm 2016.1 trial version

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am getting `[TypeError: no access]` in WebStorm 2016.1 version while debugging a node js project.

How to remove this error?

node -v : v5.5.0
npm -v : 3.3.12